# Django radio form showing ['on'] for the POST values

Tags: django, django-forms

When I working with Django forms, I need to get the selected radio button id on submit. But when I log the value of post data I came to see that request.POST selected radio as 'sample': ['on'].

> template/detail.html

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="radio" name="sample" id="r1">
    <label for="r1">Radio 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="sample" id="r2">
    <label for="r2">Radio 2</label>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

> views.py

```
print (request.POST)
```

> print result

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['exomyfdxW1uPeZtZA46SgWG9UVxX8iY6SGypagSDmkYdeFcifCOXRiXQv2TIgp2A'], 'sample': ['on']}>
```

Why is that coming like that is there any problem in my code.

Comment: What were you expecting to see? You do not set the `value` of the radio buttons.

Comment: sorry i think that its id will be passed

Comment: Try `<input type="radio" name="sample" id="r1" value="r1">`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the inputs a value.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('show_10') }}" value="1">
```